# what's the difference between (4,) and (4,1) for the shape in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two ndarray `A` and `B`, one has the shape `(4,)` and another `(4,1)`.

When I want to calculate the cosine distance using [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine), it throws some exceptions that complains the two objects `are not aligned`

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One is a 1-dimensional array, the other is a 2-dimensional array.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(4).reshape(4,1)
>>> a
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> a.ravel()
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a.squeeze()
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a[:,0]
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>>
>>> a[:,0].shape
(4,)
```

Comment: How can a convert a 4*1 array to a vector with 4-element?

Comment: There's also `.squeeze()` [(docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).

Comment: @mgilson Sorry.. the `ravel()` change the shape of `(4,1)` to `(1,)`, how can I change the shape from `(4,1)` to `(4,)`

Comment: @firegun Perhaps the easiest way to change [ [1], [2], [3], [4] ] to [1, 2, 3, 4] is `your_array.T`

Comment: @JonClements -- `your_array.T` gives `array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])`.  Not `array([1, 2, 3, 4])`

Comment: if you have an array `x= np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])`, shape (4,1). You can **flatten** it so it will have a shape (4,). `y = x.flatten()`. The shape of y is now (4,)

Comment: @mgilson Right you are.... My Python-fu leaves a lot to be desired  the last day or so... Maybe it's too much coffee and not enough sleep!

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi -- I think that `flatten` creates a copy, which seems unnecessary ...

Comment: @firegun: no, .ravel() changes the shape of (4,1) to (4,)