# Machine learning matrix multiplication ValueError: shapes not aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do back propagation and the error comes in at the last step of the training updating the weights.

The error is the following

```
syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta) * 0,2 
ValueError: shapes (4,) and (1,) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

I have tried several things but I can not find an helpful answer.
Here is the code

```
import numpy
import random

trainset = [[0,0,0],
            [0,0,1],
            [1,0,0],
            [1,0,1],
            [1,1,1],
            [1,1,0],
            [0,1,1]]

answerset = numpy.array([[0],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[1]])
def sigmoid(z, deriv=False):
    if deriv==True:
        return z*(1-z)
    return 1/(1+numpy.exp(-z))

sigmoid(45)

syn0 = 2*numpy.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*numpy.random.random((4,1)) - 1

for i in range(60000):
    an = random.randint(0,len(trainset)-1)
    l0 = trainset[an]
    l1 = sigmoid(numpy.dot(l0,syn0))
    l2 = sigmoid(numpy.dot(l1,syn1))
    #print("l2"l2)
    l2_error = answerset[an] - l2
    if(i % 10000) == 0:
        print(l2_error)
    l2_delta = l2_error*sigmoid(l2, deriv=True)
    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
    l1_delta = l1_error*sigmoid(l1,deriv=True)
    print(l2_delta)
    print(l1)
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta) * 0,2
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta) * 0,2

print(l2)
```

Comment: The technical issue is that you are taking the dot product of a 4x1 array `l1.T` and a 1x1 array `l2_delta`. What is it that you want to achieve in the error line?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your numpy ndarray shapes are not identical to transpose.
you can refer below link about shapes.[docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212215/whats-the-difference-between-4-and-4-1-for-the-shape-in-numpy)